# Wrapping an Angular 2 component in another component from parent module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to break my app apart into smaller modules in Angular 2.  I got the module part down and I'm attempting to move the routes to each module.  Everything seems to be going ok, except, my active route component doesn't seem to be wrapped in the parent modules component. Let me try to explain.

When you have one module in Angular (app.module.ts), you usually have a component by the same name (app.component.ts).  The app.component contains a  tag which lets angular know where to insert the active route view. Now let's say I have a module called admin.module.  I would like to have a component called admin.component that wraps any of the active components under it, just like the app.component does for routes under app.module.

I essentially want a template for each module along the way. Hitting the company edit route of my application, I'd like:

```
App.module (using app.component.html)
     Admin.module (using admin.component.html)
          Company.module (using company.component.html)
               Company-Edit.component (using company-edit.component.html)
```

Am I thinking about this the wrong way, or is this totally possible, but I'm missing something?

UPDATE:  I feel like I'm not being specific enough so here's some code. Here's a link to a plnkr I created.  When clicking the "admin page" link I would like the admin.component's html wrapping the admin-page.component's html

https://plnkr.co/edit/XhlLJId6Ua8At5z1ZNlz?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a child router outlet, you need to define a child route. I modified your plunker as follows:

```
  RouterModule.forChild([
    { 
      path: 'admin', 
      component: AdminComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'page', component: AdminPageComponent  }
      ]
    }
  ])
],
```

I updated the plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/AdUZ34JGwp4o4cpYrNuy?p=preview

And to not get in trouble with the SO police, I won't mention that I also have a routing course that may help you.

Comment: you rule!!! That's exactly what it was! I will totally check out your unmentioned course, we have a subscription to PluralSight as one of the perks at my job.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up multiple route hierarchies to manage your routes.

```
App Component
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> // <-Regular or admin goes here

- Regular site component
    <header></header>
    <menu></menu>
    <router-outlet> // <-Regular features get routed here
    <footer></footer>

- Admin site component
    <admin-header></admin-header>
    <router-outlet> // <-Admin features get routed here
    <admin-footer></admin-footer>
```

Comment: The root problem I'm running into is admin section vs regular section.  The admin section needs to look completely different from the regular site section.  My idea, was to include the header, top menu and footer in the site module's SiteComponent html, and include the admin menu, admin header, etc in the admin modules AdminComponent's html.  Without this, I'd have to include all of those things on each page inside their respective modules. CompanyEditComponent's html would have <admin-header/><admin-menu/><!---content---></admin-footer> along with every other admin page.

Comment: Ah ... I see. Then you do want hierarchies, but not just one. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: It would sure be nice if it was a *requirement* for anyone that down votes to leave a reason!!

Comment: Thanks for the update @DeborahK! I've tried setting it up this way, the problem I'm having is, the components for their respective modules don't show up like the AppComponent does.  Is there some type of thing you need to configure in the module itself to automatically load the component of the same name?  Like, if I have RegularModule, how do I configure it to automatically wrap anything under it in RegularComponent?

Comment: I feel like there's something I'm not doing when configuring my routes.  I'll update my question to explain what I'm doing a little better.

Comment: The reason you got down voted was because you didn't answer the right question initially and thusly were using it as a way to promote your Pluralsight course.  Downvote was deserved.

Comment: @ChrisLees I go through this in detail in my course, which I won't mention. But you can look at the code for it here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted (Check out the APM - Final folder)

Comment: And your mental model of the relationship between the modules and components may not be exactly correct. Angular modules are just groups of functionality. They don't automatically load or show or necessarily map to any specific components.

Comment: I think you're right.  I updated the original question with a plnkr showing what I have so far.